# Unity3d import file on iOS device

Tags: c#, unity, ios

im trying to figure out how to recall an external file in runtime on iOS device. I've already tried using Application.data+"/Raw/MY_FILE", with Application.streamingAssetsPath+"/MY_FILE", and with Application.persistentData+"/Raw/MY_FILE" (but, if i dont get wrong, persistentData is used for write, i need just of reading).

Please, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added your file inside a folder named "**StreamingAssets**" in Unity Editor?

So, you can get it in runtime using this path: **Application.dataPath + "/Raw/YOUR FILE NAME"**.

More info: [Streaming Assets](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/StreamingAssets.html)